# Varnish - Bypass Cache for IP Address

Tags: varnish

We're using Varnish 3.0.3. Varnish is behind a load balancer.

We would like to bypass the Varnish cache for a particular IP address. After doing research, I found the following. Unfortunately, it is not working.

```
    acl passem { "7x.xxx.xxx.xxx"; }
    sub vcl_recv {
    if (!(client.ip ~ passem)) {
    return (pass);
            }
    }
```

This appears in `varnishlog` `"6 VCL_acl   c NO_MATCH passem"`

I'm not sure what is wrong. The only thing I can think of is Varnish is not seeing the incoming IP address. This is what I see in `varnishlog`.

```
    6 RxHeader     c X-Real-IP: "7x.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    6 RxHeader     c X-Forwarded-For: "7x.xxx.xxx.xxx"

    6 SessionOpen  c 10.10.10.4 58143 0.0.0.0:80
    6 ReqStart     c 10.10.10.4 58143 1026834560
```

The RxHeader is receiving the correct IP and matches the `acl passem`, but I don't know if `acl passem`is instead referencing the `SessionOpen` IP address, which is the IP address of the load balancer.

Answer (score 4):

In Varnish, `"X-Real-IP"` and `"http.x-forwarded-for"` are strings and `"client.ip"` is an object.

Extra code is required to copy the IP address from the `"X-Forwarded-For"` header into Varnish's client_ip structure.

Below is what was required to make it work. This worked successfully. Credit goes to  http://zcentric.com/2012/03/16/varnish-acl-with-x-forwarded-for-header/

```
    C{
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    }C
    acl passem { "7x.xxx.xxx.xxx"; }
    sub vcl_recv {
    C{
    struct sockaddr_storage *client_ip_ss = VRT_r_client_ip(sp);
    struct sockaddr_in *client_ip_si = (struct sockaddr_in *) client_ip_ss;
    struct in_addr *client_ip_ia = &(client_ip_si->sin_addr);
    char *xff_ip = VRT_GetHdr(sp, HDR_REQ, "\020X-Forwarded-For:");

    if (xff_ip != NULL) {
    inet_pton(AF_INET, xff_ip, client_ip_ia);
    }
    }C
    if (!(client.ip ~ passem)) {
    return (pass);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, any idea how to do the same in Varnish4 ?
sp is not defined in Varnish4. I've tried this approac http://jan.bogutzki.de/Artikel/395/set-ttl-in-varnish-4.html but I get a "initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
in struct sockaddr_storage *client_ip_ss = VRT_r_client_ip(ctx);
" error probably because the type has also been changed.

Comment: (continue from above)
The code I'm trying to use is:
`struct sockaddr_storage *client_ip_ss = VRT_r_client_ip(ctx);
struct sockaddr_in *client_ip_si = (struct sockaddr_in *) client_ip_ss;
struct in_addr *client_ip_ia = &(client_ip_si->sin_addr);
const struct gethdr_s hdr = { HDR_REQ, "20X-Forwarded-For:" };
char *xff_ip = VRT_GetHdr(ctx, &hdr);`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your client.ip will be the real IP, not anything forwarded in headers. Instead you need to use the correct header `req.http.X-Real-IP` for instance.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't that easy, but your post certainly pointed me in the right direction to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In current varnish-cache versions you can use `std.ip()`, e.g.

```
import std;

sub vcl_recv {
  if (std.ip(req.http.X-Real-IP) !~ passem) {
    return (pass);
  }
}
```